# Replace column and extend index in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame *x* and I would like to replace one column with Series *y*

```
x = DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['C1','C2'], index=['a','b'])

   C1  C2
a   1   2
b   3   4

y = Series([5,6,7], index=['a','b','c'])

a    5
b    6
c    7
```

Simple replacement works fine but keeps original index of DataFrame

```
x['C1'] = y

   C1  C2
a   5   2
b   6   4
```

I need to have union of indeces of *x* and *y*. One solution would be to reindex before replacement

```
x = x.reindex(x.index.union(y.index), copy=False)
x['C1'] = y

   C1   C2
a   5  2.0
b   6  4.0
c   7  NaN
```

Is there simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

Turn `y` into a `DataFrame` first with `to_frame`

```
y.to_frame('C1').combine_first(x)

   C1   C2
a   5  2.0
b   6  4.0
c   7  NaN
```

---

#### [`align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) and `assign`

Use `align` to... align the indices

```
x, y = x.align(y, axis=0)

x.assign(C1=y)

   C1   C2
a   5  2.0
b   6  4.0
c   7  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your solution but more succinct, you use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), then [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
res = x.reindex(x.index | y.index).assign(C1=y)

print(res)

   C1   C2
a   5  2.0
b   6  4.0
c   7  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cat try use join:

```
pd.DataFrame(y,columns=['C1']).join(x[['C2']])
```

Output:

```
   C1  C2
a   5  2.0
b   6  4.0
c   7  NaN
```

Comment: I like this better, though it is the same concept `x[['C2']].join(y.rename('C1'))[x.columns]`  If you wanted to get cute with the unpacking `x[['C2']].join(y.rename('C1'))[[*x]]`

Comment: @piRSquared Year, really this better solution)

Comment: @piRSquared Although not, you don't get what PyJan need (shape 2*2, but he want 3*2)

Comment: That is a good point.  The how needs to be set to `outer`.  And now I like it less (-:  `x[['C2']].join(y.rename('C1'), how='outer')[[*x]]`.  However, that is `True` for you as well.  The default is `left` join.

Comment: I think that combine_first is the way to go for me as it doesn't need to use 'C2'. I have more columns in x in production.

Comment: @PyJan that is true, however, you can fix that with `x.drop('C1', 1).join(y.rename('C1'), how='outer')[[*x]]`

Comment: @piRSquared really) I forgot about `how='outer'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` but you will have to fix the column names, i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([x.loc[:, 'C2'], y], axis = 1)
```

which gives,

> ```
>     C2  0
> a  2.0  5
> b  4.0  6
> c  NaN  7
> ```